# Getting default Stylesheet in Python QT widgets

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

How can i get the default stylesheet colors in python  using pyqt

I assigned a `StyleSheet` for a `QGroupBox` when its activated

```
self.State.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox { background-color: rgb(0,255,0,20%); border:1px solid rgb(255, 170, 255); }")
```

I need to have it set to defaults when this particular `QGroupBox` is disabled or deactivated

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to a string before changing it (it's a [R/W property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop)):

```
default_style_sheet = self.State.styleSheet()

# ...

self.State.setStyleSheet(fancy_style_sheet)

# ...

self.State.setStyleSheet(default_style_sheet)
```

Answer (score 0):

To restore a previous non-default stylesheet, you can do as Felipe Lema suggests.

To restore a default one, you can use an empty string and call directly:

```
self.State.setStyleSheet("").
```